# Pandas for filtering a table with duplicate values based on a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am trying to parse a table using Pandas. The input looks like this:

**target    query    score** 
A            X            5 
B            X            1 
C            Y            7 
D            Z            10 
E            Z            9

I'd like to look for duplicates in the query column, but keep the row with a better (lower) score.
Output:

**target    query    score** 
B            X            1 
C            Y            7 
E            Z            9

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['query'], keep='last')`

Comment: @ScottBoston probably add a sort in there on the score column just incase

Comment: @Datanovice is correct `df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['query'], keep='last')`

Comment: Thanks y'all, your solution worked perfectly!